# color page's dot in a Titanium.UI.Scrollableview

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to use a custom color or image for the white dot of the `pagingControl` in a `Titanium.UI.Scrollableview`?

```
var scrollableView =Titanium.UI.createScrollableView({
        views:[view1,view2,view3],
        showPagingControl:true,
        pagingControlHeight:30,
        pagingControlColor:'transparent',
        width : 200,
        height : 90,
        left : 120,
        top:40,
        maxZoomScale:2.0,
        currentPage:0
});
```

Comment: ok
 i received an answer in Titanium Appcelerator site

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130397/color-pages-dot-in-a-titaniumuiscrollableview#227004

Comment: post the answer here and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer (as you said) found on http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130397/color-pages-dot-in-a-titaniumuiscrollableview#227004 :

sorry, i dont have an example.. but here is it:

create a container view.

then create the small "dot" views, and add them to the container view. set the positions.

there is an event, when the scrollable view "scrolls" or changing.. and you can set the small dot view to active (of course you should set up the active state as well)